# Using the fact that $n^3 + 5n$ is divisible by $6$, infer that $n^4 - 2n^3 + 11n^2 + 14n$ is always divisible by $24$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring

The problem is as stated in the title. I've tried factorization, but it doesn't seem to yield anything. Any help is greatly appreciated. Also please don't use modular arithmetic, thank you.

Comment: You tell tales of your great efforts but no proof has been given as of yet; as such I shall abstain from helping as this is not a do my homework site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that
\begin{align}
n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)&=n^4-6n^3+11n^2-6n=\color{red}{[n^4-2n^3+11n^2+14n]}-4\color{blue}{[n^3+5n]}.
\end{align}

Comment: How did you see that! Your solution is brilliant..

Comment: @ShreyAryan Intuition. Let $A=n^4-2n^3+11n^2+14n$ and $B=n^3+5n$. I guessed that it must be the case that $A+\alpha B=C$ where $C$ must be obviously divisible by $24$ and $\alpha$ is divisible by $4$. Considering what $A$ is, I tried $C=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$.

Comment: That's bloody brilliant, never would've seen this. Thank you!

Comment: @Airdish If you are going to assume known the above, then you can do it without even using the hypothesis - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$P(n)=n^4-2n^3+11n^2+14n=n(n+1)(n^2-3n+14)$$

►Reducing modulo $3$ $$P(n)\equiv n(n+1)(n^2-1)=(n-1)(n-1)n(n+1)\equiv 0\pmod 3$$ because has a factor which is product of three consecutive integers.

►Reducing modulo $8$ $$P(n)\equiv n(n+1)(n^2+5n+6)=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\equiv 0\pmod 8$$
because is a product of four consecutive integers.

Thus $P(n)$ is divisible by $24$ for all $n$.

NOTE.- By the way, $n^3+5n$ is always divisible by $6$ (reduce modulo 3).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively $\,\displaystyle f(n) = (n\!+\!1)n(n\!-\!1)(n\!-\!2) + 12(n\!+\!1)n = \color{#c00}{24}{n+1\choose 4}+ \color{#c00}{24}{n+1\choose 2}$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use that $n^3 + 5n$ is divisible by $6$:
$$
n^4 - 2n^3 + 11n^2 + 14n
=
24\left(\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{4}\right)
$$